# How to assign elements into the diagonal of a 3d matrix efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, diagonal

```
a=np.zeros((3,3,3))
b=np.arange(3)
c=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
```

I wanna put the elements of the array `b` or `c` along the diagonal (or above/below the diagonal) of the 3d matrix (tensor) `a` with respect to a specific axis.

I tired `numpy.diagflat`, but it only works for 2d matrix.

For instance, how to make the following matrix?

```
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  2.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  2.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  2.]]])
```

Answer (score 6):

For the main diagonals you can use `np.einsum`. For example:

```
>> np.einsum('iii->i', a)[...] = b
>>> a
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  2.]]])
```

Or:

```
>>> np.einsum('iji->ji', a)[...] = c
>>> a
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 3.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 6.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  4.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  7.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  5.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  8.]]])
```

**Edit:** Broadcasting works normally:

```
>>> np.einsum('ijj->ij', a)[...] = b
>>> a
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  2.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  2.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  2.]]])
```

Subdiagonals also work but are more tricky as some manual slicing is required. For example:

```
>>> a=np.zeros((3,3,3))
>>> np.einsum('iij->ij', a[:2,1:])[...] = c[1:]
>>> a
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 6.,  7.,  8.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Comment: A rising star in the `numpy` tag!

Comment: You seem in a generous mood today. Or are you talking about `einsum`?

Comment: Thx, does `np.einsum` assign the elements one by one or do all of them in the same time?

Comment: Nah, it was just a compliment. Maybe if I finally read some tutorial on einsum I'll be able to get some rep in the `numpy` tag ;)

Comment: It does neither. What it does is to create a writable view into the original array. We then use this view to manually assign. My hunch is that this should be pretty fast at least for large arrays.

Comment: @kinderchan, look at the `__array_interface__` of these `a` and the `einsums`.  `einsum` is creating a `view`, with special striding to access these diagonal elements.  Most cleaver, this is!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, thanks then! I just had a look at the rankings page - I wasn't aware.

Comment: thx, I re-editted my question and I wanna get the matrix I added, does `np.einsum` still work and how?

Comment: @kinderchan, the key to using `einsum` here is that it creates a `view`.  Anything that can be done with a regular `view` (e.g. `x[1:10,:]`), should work with one produced by `einsum`.   But you can test this yourself.  Once you understand the pieces you can use them in various ways. (edit) `np.einsum('iii->i',A)[...] += 100` works

Comment: @kinderchan I've edited the answer and added your specific example.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, can `np.einsum` work on off-diagonal (above/below the diagonal) ?

Comment: @kinderchan not by itself, but you can combine it with slicing to get arbitrary subdiagonals as I show in the last example.

Comment: I appreciate your help, and I'm trying in that way.

Comment: @kinderchan Do you mean subdiagonal (for example i==j+1) or triangle (for example i > j)? If you mean triangle you can't use `einsum` or any view-based approach because triangles cannot be expressed as a product of strided intervals.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, I mean subdiagonal (`i==j+1` and `j-1`). I already did it by slicing the original matrix to a specific shape successfully. Thx so much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

If a sparse matrix will serve your needs, here are some resources:

http://www.janeriksolem.net/sparray-sparse-n-dimensional-arrays-in.html

[sparse 3d matrix/array in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685128/sparse-3d-matrix-array-in-python)