# how to store/retrieve/work with a sparse 3D matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

this question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685128/sparse-3d-matrix-array-in-python). However, that was 10 years ago; I'd like to bring it back, to see if there are new ways to store/retrieve/work with a 3D sparse matrix.

I know scipy.sparse still doesn't support 3D matrices, but maybe some other library/tool does it.

Comment: That question may be 10 years old, but some of the answers are  much newer.

Comment: you're correct. Sorry for not checking carefully.

Comment: https://sparse.pydata.org/en/stable/