# Multiply high order matrices with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

I created this toy problem that reflects my much bigger problem:

```
import numpy as np

ind = np.ones((3,2,4)) # shape=(3L, 2L, 4L)
dist = np.array([[0.1,0.3],[1,2],[0,1]]) # shape=(3L, 2L)

ans = np.array([np.dot(dist[i],ind[i]) for i in xrange(dist.shape[0])]) # shape=(3L, 4L)
print ans

""" prints:
   [[ 0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4]
    [ 3.   3.   3.   3. ]
    [ 1.   1.   1.   1. ]]
"""
```

I want to do it as fast as possible, so using numpy's functions to calculate `ans` should be the best approach, since this operation is heavy and my matrices are quite big.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490961/numpy-multiplying-a-matrix-with-a-3d-tensor-suggestion), but the shapes are different and I cannot understand which `axes` I should use for this problem. However, I'm certain that [tensordot](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) should have the answer. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I accepted [@ajcr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30817037/3523490), but please read my own answer as well, it may help others...

Comment: great (EDIT: I accepted @ajcr's answer, but please read my own answer as well.) it will help to others..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `np.einsum` to do the operation since it allows for very careful control over which axes are multiplied and which are summed:

```
>>> np.einsum('ijk,ij->ik', ind, dist)
array([[ 0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4],
       [ 3. ,  3. ,  3. ,  3. ],
       [ 1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ]])
```

The function multiplies the entries in the first axis of `ind` with the entries in the first axis of `dist` (subscript `'i'`). Ditto for the second axis of each array (subscript `'j'`). Instead of returning a 3D array, we tell einsum to sum the values along axis `'j'` by omitting it from the output subscripts, thereby returning a 2D array.

---

`np.tensordot` is more difficult to apply to this problem. It automatically sums the products of axes. However, we want *two* sets of products but to sum only *one* of them.

Writing `np.tensordot(ind, dist, axes=[1, 1])` (as in the answer you linked to) computes the correct values for you, but returns a 3D array with shape `(3, 4, 3)`. If you can afford the memory cost of a larger array, you could use:

```
np.tensordot(ind, dist, axes=[1, 1])[0].T
```

This gives you the correct result, but because `tensordot` creates a much larger-than-necessary array first, `einsum` seems to be a better option.

Answer (score 16):

Following [@ajcr's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30817037/3523490), I wanted to determine which method is the fastest, so I used `timeit` :

```
import timeit

setup_code = """
import numpy as np
i,j,k = (300,200,400)
ind = np.ones((i,j,k)) #shape=(3L, 2L, 4L)
dist = np.random.rand(i,j) #shape=(3L, 2L)
"""

basic ="np.array([np.dot(dist[l],ind[l]) for l in xrange(dist.shape[0])])"
einsum = "np.einsum('ijk,ij->ik', ind, dist)"
tensor= "np.tensordot(ind, dist, axes=[1, 1])[0].T"

print "tensor - total time:", min(timeit.repeat(stmt=tensor,setup=setup_code,number=10,repeat=3))
print "basic - total time:", min(timeit.repeat(stmt=basic,setup=setup_code,number=10,repeat=3))
print "einsum - total time:", min(timeit.repeat(stmt=einsum,setup=setup_code,number=10,repeat=3))
```

The surprising results were:

```
tensor - total time: 6.59519493952
basic - total time: 0.159871203461
einsum - total time: 0.263569731028
```

So obviously using tensordot was the wrong way to do it (not to mention `memory error` in bigger examples, just as @ajcr stated).

Since this example was small, I changed the matrices size to be `i,j,k = (3000,200,400)`, flipped the order just to be sure it has not effect and set up another test with higher numbers of repetitions:

```
print "einsum - total time:", min(timeit.repeat(stmt=einsum,setup=setup_code,number=50,repeat=3))
print "basic - total time:", min(timeit.repeat(stmt=basic,setup=setup_code,number=50,repeat=3))
```

The results were consistent with the first run:

```
einsum - total time: 13.3184077671
basic - total time: 8.44810031351
```

However, testing another type of size growth - `i,j,k = (30000,20,40)` led the following results:

```
einsum - total time: 0.325594117768
basic - total time: 0.926416766397
```

See the comments for explanations for these results.

The moral is, when looking for the fastest solution for a specific problem, try to generate data that is as similar to the original data as possible, in term of types and shapes. In my case `i` is much smaller than `j,k` and so I stayed with the ugly version, which is also the fastest in this case.

Comment: Interesting to see that `einsum` isn't necessarily quicker than using `dot` in a loop! I think that if the first dimension is large, the `for` loop will drag `dot` down quite a bit and `einsum` might be the faster option. I tried with `i,j,k = (300000,20,40)` and got `dot` as 1.11 s compared to `einsum` at 273 ms. As your answer shows, it's definitely worth testing the methods on the kind of shapes you're working with so you know what's fastest.

Comment: @ajcr I totally agree! I'll add these results as well